# NuGet vs Package Manager Console

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

I use mainly the `NuGet manager` to install packages.
If I use the `package manager console`, I can see all the added/modified files in the console log...

But if I use the NuGet manager, is there a way to see what files were affected by the package update/install?

Answer (score 1):

You can always open the package in the [Nuget Package Explorer](http://npe.codeplex.com/).

or, after it is unpacked, you can just look in the packages/{package folder}/lib|content|etc folder and look at the contents

Comment: I understand, but when installing, some files are deleted, some other are modified, some other files are added. I need to see the modifications, not just the final state...

Comment: well, if you use source control, the first time you install it (before ignoring) then there is likely a diff.  I don't know how other than that

Comment: from my last synchronisation with the TFS I achieved to reinstall/uninstall a lot of packages, and now this is a big mess with it... This is because my extraction scope was the migration from a non-packages solution to a packaged one

Comment: in general, I expect files mostly to be added or overwritten.  If things are getting modified / deleted all together, that is likely coming from a script.